# Jquery Cookie show/hide

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using carhart's jquery cookie plugin, and I wrote this code to show/hide #bounceBar on click of #bounceStart.  It doesn't work, however.  What am I doing wrong?

This error shows up on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie'
```

Code:

```
$('#bounceStart').click(function() {
  //$('#bounceBar').show();
  $.cookie('bounce', 'on');
});

$('#bounceBar #off').click(function() {
  //$('#bounceBar').show();
  $.cookie('bounce', 'off');
});

var bounce_on = $.cookie('bounce') == 'on';
if( bounce_on ) { 
  $('#bounceBar').show(); 
} else {             
  $('#bouncebar').hide(); 
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  What **does** happen?  Are there errors on the console, etc.

Comment: Nothing happens at all.  When I click #bounceStart, nothing happens.  No errors.

Comment: Make sure you wrap this entire code in $(document).ready(function(){ //code } );

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do some logic based on cookie set/unset (Not sure) ...Hope this helps..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bounceStart').click(function() {
            //$('#bounceBar').show();
            $.cookie('bounce', 'on');
        });

        $('#off').click(function() { //off can directly call,since it is an ID
            //$('#bounceBar').show();
            $.cookie('bounce', 'off');
        });

        var bounce_on = $.cookie('bounce'); //or some method to get the cookie
        if( bounce_on == 'on' ) {
              $('#bounceBar').show();
         }
        else {   
               $('#bouncebar').hide(); 
        }


});
```

Comment: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html

Some easy ways for javascript cookies...